# context in methods dart class

Tags: flutter, onclick, widget

Hi how can I access context in Widgets, below is the code. In top layout Widget I have onclick for IconButton in which it is expecting context. So how can make context available for that onClick??

```
 Widget toplayout = new Container(
      width: 70,
      height: 70,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            iconSize: 30,
            onPressed: () {
             // Here i want context 
              if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              } else {
                SystemNavigator.pop();
              }
            },
          ),
          new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
              child: new Text("Day 1",
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  )))
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Where do you want to call this piece of code?

Comment: inside body of a StatelessWidget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap IconButton with [Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) class:

```dart
  Builder(builder: (context) => IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    iconSize: 30,
    onPressed: () {
     // Here i want context 
      if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      } else {
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      }
    },
  ),)
```